# Is UUID random enough for password recovery link?

Tags: perl, security, uuid

Does [Data::UUID](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::UUID) generates secure and random sequences? Is it ok to use it to generate password recovery link?
For example:

```
use Data::UUID;
my $u = Data::UUID->new;
my $uuid = $u->create_from_name_str(NameSpace_URL, 'www.example.com');
#then add $uuid to db
#and send email to user
```

Comment: Did you even try running this program?  `create_from_name_str` isn't random at all.  Your example generates `A777199A-C522-31C4-8F4B-335FEEC7215B`.

Comment: looks pretty random from first glance

Comment: Did you run it twice?  You can't get any idea of how random the output is from running code once.

Comment: Something went wrong:) `create_uuid_as_string(UUID_V4, UUID_NS_URL, 'example.com');` in module UUID::Tiny looks more random, but is it random enought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I'd use [UUID::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/UUID::Tiny) because that's capable of generating version 4 UUIDs, which are more random. However, in either case the modules are just using Perl's `rand` function which isn't considered random enough for serious crypto work.

Still, this is likely to be random enough for a typical password-recovery e-mail. Especially if the password recovery link is only kept working for, say, 24 hours and stops working after that.

It really depends on what you're securing though. Is it a forum for posting pictures of your pets dressed in superhero costumes, or is it nuclear launch codes? If you think that your website is likely to be a target for criminal elements, then it might be wise to opt for something stronger.

A fairly good random string with low collision probability can be generated using:

```
use Crypt::PRNG;
my $string = sprintf(
    q/%08x%s/,
    time(),
    Crypt::PRNG->new->bytes_hex(24),
);
```

Comment: `ATTENTION! UUID::Tiny uses Perl's rand() to create the basic random numbers, so the created v4 UUIDs are not cryptographically strong!` And unfortunately this is not site for posting pets pictures:( `Crypt::PRNG` is not unique?

Comment: If it was guaranteed to be unique, then it wouldn't be random, would it? Hence adding the timestamp, to add some uniqueness. (For all intents and purposes, the chances of generating the same random 24 bytes of data twice in the same second is zero.)

Answer (score 1):

Data::UUID can generate either [version 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID#Version_1_.28MAC_address.29) (`create`) or [version 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID#Version_3_.28MD5_hash.29) (`create_from_name`) UUIDs.  Neither of those is random.  Version 1 is your MAC address plus a timestamp, and version 3 is a MD5 hash of the string you passed in.

Comment: What module should I use to generate good random UUID or something else?